# How to insert bit value in mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

so i saw this cmd example,

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`ID`, `enabled`)
VALUES (1,b'1'),(2,b'0');
```

Then i put these in node.js,

```
const sqlCmd = `insert into my_table (ID, enabled)
                values (?, ?)`;

try {
    const param = [1, 1];
    return await dbPool.execSqlCmd(sqlCmd, param)
}
```

it seems to be working when i check the db
select enabled+0 from my_table.

still not very sure if it really works or not, can someone comment on my code ?
Thanks !

Comment: I have no clue of node.js - But it should work with integers. Into a `BIT(1)` column you can store `0, 1, true, false, 0x00, 0x01, b'0', b'1', x'00', x'01'` but not srings like `'0'` or `'1'`. If you'd want to bind a string you would probably need `values (?, ?+0)`

Comment: What's the schema here? Using `b'1'`, which is a BINARY string (e.g. no text encoding, raw data), *not* a binary value as in 101001.

Comment: @tadman it's bit(1) in mysql